# Can we execute multiple profiles in the same pom.xml file

Tags: maven, profiling

I have created a Maven project in Eclipse and have 2 xml files in it. I have created 2 profiles "TestNG.xml" and "TestNG2.xml" in the pom.xml file for my Maven project.
I ran the following command from command prompt
- mvn test

Expected behavior : TCs under both the TestNG.xml and TestNG2.xml files should get executed.
Actual behavior : Only TCs under TestNG2.xml file is getting executed.

NOTE :- When i am executing the .xml files individually using the below command it works fine{TestNG.xml file has been profiled as Regression in the pom.xml file}
- mvn test -PRegression

Below is the snapshot of my code from pom.xml file

```
 <groupId>Rohit</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenProject05202020</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MavenProject05202020</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Regression</id>
 <!--  Below is MAVEN SURE FIRE PLUGIN. This will help to execute all your TCs present in your test folder{i.e.:-src/test/java}-->
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
          <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
        </profile>

<!--  Below is MAVEN SURE FIRE PLUGIN. 
        <profile>
           <id>Smoke</id>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
          <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
         </profile>
  </profiles>



<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
<!--  below is the dependency for Selenium project -->
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
      </dependency>
<!-- Below is the dependency for TESTNG. -->
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
<!--  Below is the dependency for RestAPITest project -->
      <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just define the surefire-plugin twice, these definitions will override each other.

Instead, you need to define an `<execution>` in the plugin declaration and bind it to a phase. Plugins can have more than one execution in the `<executions>` block.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!! I did try that option but no change in behavior. I browsed the internet for more answers and figured out that when you execute command "mvn test" it will execute all the TCs by default, irrespective of the TestNG.xml file name that is mentioned in "pom.xml". So defining an <execution> under plugin declaration and binding it to a phase does not work. Is there any other option where i can execute multiple TestNG.xml's from the same pom file. Profiling is one i know. Is there any other way?